# return jar file name

Tags: regex

A regular expression to return logging.jar. Path can contain varying levels of depthness.

I think I need to use the '.' operator but am unsure how to handle varying amount of slashes ?

Both below test cases should return logging.jar

`C:/proj/test/tester/base/logging.jar`
`C:/proj/test/tester/base/leveldeeper/logging.jar`

Comment: Do you want the solution in regex only??

Comment: @Sunil Kumar B M I think its cleaner....

Comment: If regex is not the only solution, I have a simple solution for you

Comment: @@Sunil Kumar B M post it! thanks

Comment: I've posted the answer, take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*/([^\\.]*)\\..*`
in group 1 you'll get the name of the file.extension doesn't matter.
If you want to get name only for jar files use this pattern:
`.*/([^\\.]*)\\.jar`

`.*` is a greedy regex and it will match until the **last** `/`.After `/` there is only file's name with extension and you just need to get it's name. `[^\\.]*` is greedy too and will match until the **last** dot (`.`), in fact what you need because the last dot is the extension separator.

Answer (score 1):

`/([^/]+\.jar)$/` will give you the result in the first capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without regular expression

```
String path = "C:/proj/test/tester/base/leveldeeper/logging.jar";
String splitPath[] = path.split("/");

System.out.println("Jar File name: " + splitPath[splitPath.length - 1]);
```

Comment: it will output "logging.jar" and also you're using an array which is not necessary!!! you could do this with File. new File(path).getName() will return the same.